Switching to Dark Theme on Stack Overflow pages
I just switched to a new computer (to macOS from MS Windows).  I have
poor eyesight and depend on dark theme to be able to read my
screen.  Stack Overflow pages are currently very difficult for
me to read.  A web search informs me that there is a dark theme
preference I can set in Stack Overflow, but I've not been able
to find it.  The search result said:

Access: Log into your Stack Overflow account, go to your profile
settings, and select "Dark" under the theme preference option.

On my Stack Overflow home page if I search for "profile" I get
nothing useful.
I can't find "Profile Settings" on the Stack Overflow site.  On
the Stack Overflow corporate home page there's a menu at the top
left that disappears when the mouse moves off of the menu button
into the menu itself.  This using Chrome on MacOS.
How do I get to the profile settings and enable dark theme?

https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/me

"On my Stack Overflow home page if I search for "profile" I get nothing useful"... accessibility is not one of Stack Exchange's strong suites. You click the avatar / user icon that's to the right of the search box to access your profile page.

Another duplicate: How do I enable/disable the Light/Dark Theme on Stack Overflow?

Will we be getting a dark theme on Meta Stack Overflow? Perhaps the OP asked the question on SO to start with because they can read SO with the Dark Theme.

As far as I'm aware, only [so] was ever in scope, @MT1 .

How to apply a Dark theme using CSS could this be made to work on Meta?
